# ¿Cuándo dejó de ser "Hola" usado para llamar a los inferiores?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia

En la entrada para [hola](https://dle.rae.es/?id=KYtLWBc) en el DLE se encuentra:

> **[hola](https://dle.rae.es/?id=KYtLWBc)**
>
> Voz expr.; *cf.* ingl. *hello,* al. *hallo.*
>
> 1. *interj. U.* como salutación familiar.
> 2. interj. p. us. U. para denotar extrañeza, placentera o desagradable. U. t. repetida.
> 3. interj. desus. Era u. para llamar a los inferiores.

La tercera acepción indica que alguna vez se usó para llamar a un inferior. Esto también se puede ver en el diccionario de autoridades:

> [**HOLA**](http://web.frl.es/DA.html). interj. Modo vulgar de hablar usado para llamar a otro que es inferior. Latín. *Heus*, que es de donde viene. FIGUER. Passag. Aliv. 9. Dispenso en que useis el Hola, solo en ocasiones de visitas, por acomodaros al estilo grave de Señores.

¿Desde cuando tiene *Hola* el uso actual que le damos?

Comment: no se, pero que interesante descubrir de donde viene la palabra "hola"

Answer (score 3):

Con base en el mapa de diccionarios de la RAE, la acepción aparece como desusada desde 1992. Buscando con un poco de paciencia en el CORDE, en *Niebla* de Unamuno (1918) se usa el término como un saludo habitual. Si se revisa durante el siglo XIX, casi todos los ejemplos son del corte repetido (hola hola), lo que dejaría casi que para el final de ese siglo los inicios del saludo habitual. (Pasa algún tiempo mientras se hace popular un término en el habla y se empieza a escribir)

Answer (score 2):

El artículo siguiente analiza esta exacta pregunta, la evolución de la forma *hola*. En su conclusión dice:

> ... el empleo de la forma hola como saludo está ya normalizado en la primera mitad del siglo XIX, puesto que al aparecer en la lengua escrita es presumible que fuese de
>   uso habitual en la lengua oral, a pesar de que no se registra en el Diccionario de
>   Autoridades hasta finales de dicho siglo.
>
> - [*Análisis pragmático del marcador* hola *en el teatro de Calderón de la Barc*a](https://online.liverpooluniversitypress.co.uk/doi/abs/10.3828/bhs.2013.54)

Además hay este gráfico:

[image]